# Importing eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have an eclipse Cordova project that I am trying to import into Android Studio.
I have imported it as a gradle project and got the build.gradle files working properly.

There are 2 projects (kind of). My MainActivity (com.test.example) and CordovaLib which is imported.

However, when I try to add a module, it only allows me to use CordovaLib. As a result, the project never runs from the main activity.  I have no idea how to get it to run the main project.

My settings and project set up are below

**FOR SOME REASON I CANNOT UPLOAD IMAGES THROUGH STACKOVERFLOW**

[Project Set Up](https://ibb.co/jkdE0a)

[Run/Debug Configuration](https://ibb.co/j6nDtv)

My root build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My CordovaLib build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'example.com.test'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 24
        versionName '1.0.2'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'base'
```

My settings.gradle root file

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
```

When i try to run the project i get the following error

```
Error running CordovaLib: Default Activity Not Found
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I don't know if the build.gradle files have been muddles up, or if i'm going about this the total wrong way. Had nothing but bother for the past few days

Answer (score 1):

step by step import with above link

[Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

and this error **Error running CordovaLib: Default Activity Not Found** when occur there is no default activity set in android manifest check android mainfest of library that you import.

hope it help.

Comment: I know its because i have no activity set, but it is using the wrong project. It is loading in CordovaLib as the main project when it isnt

Comment: re-import your project remove CordovaLib from your project then re-import CordovaLib hope it help @Pooshonk